# Can't get session scoped bean on session timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session-bean

I need to get a proxied session-scoped bean on the `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()`. The objective is doing a session cleanup when it gets destroyed (either by `invalidate()` or timeout). I added the `ContextLoaderListener` to expose the context and got the bean through `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext()`.

Everything works fine if I invalidate the session myself in a Servlet, but when session times out I get an `Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread;`. I understand that the problem happens for the cleanup is being done by a internal thread of the Servlet engine, but I still need to  be able to get this bean from a `HttpSessionListener`.

I've seem many of the same question around, no one got a solution, this is why I'm asking again.

My **applicationContext.xml** has no bean declaration, as I'm using annotations.

This the **bean** I need to access when session times out:

```java
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Access {

    static private int SERIAL = 0;
private int serial;

    public Access() {
            serial = SERIAL++;
    }

    public int getSerial() {
            return serial;
    }
}
```

This is the **controller** that either `create` or `destroy` the session manually.

```java
@Controller
public class Handler {

    @Autowired
    Access access;


    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public @ResponseBody String create() {
        return "Created "+access.getSerial();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/destroy")
    public @ResponseBody String destroy(HttpSession sess) {
        int val = access.getSerial();
        sess.invalidate();
        return "Destroyed "+val;
    }

}
```

And this is the **HttpSessionListener** that listen to the session destruction, ***where I need to access the the contents of the `Access` session scoped bean***.

```java
public class SessionCleanup implements HttpSessionListener {

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent ev) {

    // Get context exposed at ContextLoaderListener
    WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
        .getWebApplicationContext(ev.getSession().getServletContext());

    // Get the beans
    Access v = (Access) ctx.getBean("access");

    // prints a not-null object
    System.out.println(v);

    // this line raise the exception
    System.out.println(v.getSerial());

    }


    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent ev) {/*Nothing to do*/}

}
```

The exception below is raised at `v.getSerial()`.

```
Ago 14, 2012 11:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession expire
SEVERE: Session event listener threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.access': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:654)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:605)
    at model.Access$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$438f41a5.toString(<generated>)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2902)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler.println(SystemLogHandler.java:242)
    at service.SessionCleanup.sessionDestroyed(SessionCleanup.java:24)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:709)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.processExpires(ManagerBase.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1638)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
    ... 19 more
```

Finally, here is my **web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>session-listener-cleanup</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <listener>
      <listener-class>service.SessionCleanup</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


</web-app>
```

As I've said, everything goes nice when I invalidate the session at the controller's method `destroy`.

**UPDATE 1: POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS FOUND**

The problem happens because a request is needed in order to Spring access session beans. Event though we have a Context associated to the Thread, there is no request.

There are some possible choices here:

1. Implement the interface DisposableBean, as suggested by **alexwen**. This would imply in moving business logic to the model object [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965010/179138);
2. Implement the `DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor` also suggested by **alexwen**. This one would mean that you would need to check if the bean being disposed is a `Access` or not before doing any disposal [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965010/179138);
3. Retrieve the bean directly from the session. This way is not a very good one, as you use an undocumented behavior to achieve the result, but does work [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11979178/179138);
4. Mock a servlet request and bind it's attributes to the Thread through `RequestContextHolder`. This also leads to undocumented behavior, able of being changed in future releases [[here]](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?28389-Access-session-scoped-bean-via-HttpSessionListener&p=280143#post280143);

I didn't chose the last two, for they're not documented. Also, I didn't like the idea of scavenging every bean after a specific one. As I also don't want to mix the business logic into my model beans, I ended up by creating a `@Service` that creates the bean and also have a `destroy` method.

This method is responsible by the disposal of the access bean. I implemented the `DisposableBean` interface on the `Access` and injected the `AccessManager` service to the  `Access` bean and call the service `destroy` method. The service look like this:

```java
@Service
public class AccessManager {

    @Bean(name="access", destroyMethod="destroy")
    @Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @Autowired
    public Access create(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // creation logic
    }


    public void destroy(Access access) {
        // disposal logic
    }

}
```

Comment: As suggested by the exception, in the web.xml, you should use either DispatcherServlet or RequestContextListener/RequestContextFilter expose all http requests and bind request to thread.

Comment: @yorkw the listener is already registered and everything goes fine if I invalidate the session. The problem is the timeout. I've updated the post to include my **web.xml**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement the interface, [DisposableBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html) on your Access class Spring will invoke the method "destroy" when the Session is destroyed.

Alternatively, you can register with Spring a [DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor.html) which will have the opportunity to process all beans in the Session scope when the scope is destroyed. [Docs and instructions here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension).

If you are curious as to how Spring does all this I would encourage you to look at the DisposableBeanAdapter which Spring registers as a [HttpSessionBindingListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) with the Session.

Comment: Thanks. The destroy method does work, and I had already tried this. But this would imply in moving business logic to my model beans. I'd like to avoid it, and make services that could cleanup the mess. I'll take a look at `DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor` and `HttpSessionBidingListener`.

Comment: It did work with `DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor`, but then I'll need to watch every bean on the application and look for the `Access` instances? There is no way to watch for specific instances? Gonna give a look and search for a scope destruction awareness. Thanks.

Comment: Spring offers no means to filter beans passed to the PostProcessor, that I can see. Generally, I have seen with the *Aware interfaces in Spring is that they operate on all beans in the Context. One potential way around that (as you seem adverse to doing instanceof checks) would be to create a specific context for beans you want to be aware of their destruction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens for there is no request bound to the listener, although there is a context bound to it. The session scope needs a request to be resolved.

Reading around, I found that the scope beans are stored into the `HttpSession` itself. If all I need is to grab a session-scoped bean, I just need to get the session attribute with the bean name (`session.getAttribute('beanName')`).

The only trick here is that proxied beans, as is the case above, are prefixed with the string `scopedTarget.`, so to grab the `Access` bean, I just need to call the attribute named `scopedTarget.access`. No need for the **ContextLoaderListener** also.

All I need to do, to get the bean above, is to implement `HttpSessionListener` and write the following method:

```java
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent ev) {

    // Get the session
    HttpSession session = ev.getSession();

    // Get the access bean
    Access access = (Access) session.getAttribute("scopedTarget.access");

    // Print the serial
    System.out.println(access.getSerial());

}
```

**IMPORTANT:** I don't know if this is the best approach, though. I believe this is risky, for there is no guarantees that the bean name will keep the same rules as now.

Comment: Your last statement I believe is the most important. Since this is undocumented behavior and just a side effect of their implementation in Spring it may not be supported in future releases.

Comment: I'll try to investigate the best way to grab these attributes and if this is recommended to get this way.

Comment: Still useful info in 2021